# Eclipse Scala IDE slow and crashes caused by Slick generated HCon (HList)

Tags: eclipse, scala, slick, scala-ide, slick-2.0

I'm using Eclipse 4.3.2 Scala IDE 3.0.3 and so far it's been fine. Lately however I've started using Slick 2.0.1 [code generator](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/code-generation.html) and since there are some pretty heavy tables on my database (up to 200 columns), Slick code generator uses "HList implementation for overcoming Scala’s tuple size limit".

This causes the whole load of problems:

1. Opening the file containing code generator generated classes freezes eclipse for a few minutes.
2. I'm often getting `eclipse Error in Scala compiler java.lang.StackOverflowError` at which point I am advised to close the application...
3. "Content Assist" crashes with the following error:

`The 'Scala Completion Proposal Computer' proposal computer from the 'org-scala-ide.sdt.core' plug-in did not complete normally. Unable to instantiate the extension.`

4."Updating occurrence annotations" runs for ages

I'm guessing all these problems are memory related (let me know otherwise), so I've tried increasing memory settings on `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Xss8M
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m #this one seems to be irrelevant since I'm running Java 8
-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
```

Is there anything else I can do to make my workflow bearable?

My stack:

Scala 2.10.4 / Play Framework 2.2.2 / Java 8 / Ubuntu 13.10 64 Bit

**UPDATE:** This is the file causing the problem: http://pastebin.com/BDhhPHXB

So far I've noticed this: Opening the file / saving it / compiling it / using code suggestions takes roughly 70 seconds every time. So I'm guessing the code of this file is run against the compiler on pretty much any action involving it?

Comment: Is your Scala IDE using the Scala 2.10.4 presentation compiler or an earlier one? That may be the problem. It needs to be >=2.10.4 Also approximately how many tables using HLists do you have with how many columns?

Comment: @cvogt Well I have Scala 2.10.4 installed on my system, but how do I find out if Scala IDE is actually using it? I coudn't find any settings regarding this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, but that could be the reason. Or a large number of tables. Slick 2.1 or 2.2 will probably switch to generating classes for >22 instead of HLists.

Comment: @cvogt at the moment I have only one large table in my `Tables.scala` - that's about 160 columns and that is causing all the problems I mentioned above.

Comment: 3.0.3 final comes with Scala 2.10.4. You can find the exact version by looking at Eclipse `Installation Details`, or you can get a simplified, copy-paste-able number if you go to the menu Scala/Report a Bug.

Comment: `occurrence annotations` is unfortunately slow, and off by default. I recommend disabling it, and only enabling it when you need it (easy to add a shortcut, if there's no default).

Comment: @IulianDragos What is "occurrence annotations" and how do I disable it?

Comment: Caballero, could you try what compile times you get with sbt? And could you maybe post the generated code somewhere to look at?

Comment: @cvogt compilation time of this particular file is roughly a minute: http://pastebin.com/BDhhPHXB . This is just a handful of tables, the whole database makes it impossible to work with.

Comment: @Caballero, please check [this page](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/typingviewing/mark-occurrences.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the crashes, I have been able to reproduce a compiler stack overflow with your code exactly once and I reported a bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8477  Increasing the java stack size may help, but it is suspicious that it only happens sporadically.

Regarding the freezes and the compile time: I investigated compile times with Slick HLists and eventhough they have gotten a lot better in Scala 2.10.4, they still seem to be slow (and actually exponential) when we get to sizes of a few hundreds elements as with your tables, that have a few hundred columns. This may be a Scala compiler bug or there may just be room for improvement or maybe nothing could be done in the compiler. At best Slick could work around that if we find multiple way to express the same thing and one is faster then the existing one, but that's speculation. I produced a minimized code example and requested an improvement of the compiler: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8478

**UPDATE:** We are working on a workaround for Slick. Not done yet. https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/749

Comment: Thanks, fingers crossed Scala 2.11 and Play 2.3 will make this more bearable.

Comment: Added link to PR where we are working on a workaround.